# How can I use XML files as database and access it through JAX-B API?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I want to build a lightweight, "database" backed application, where the data can be stored in XML--- and use jaxB to move data to and from the persistant state.

However, I havent been able to find any good resources regarding using an XML file as a database for a live application --- although this is an unorthodox method, for my particular app, it's ideal (small data, needs to be user editable, users are smart enough to edit XML without screwing up).....

My concerns are obvious :locking /transactions/etc.... Unless someone has already addressed these issues, it might be a bad idea to try to use an XML file as a live data store  .  I Don't need 100 transactions a minute... But some degree of support for data integrity is, of course, in my best interests.

Is there any precedent for such an application of JaxB?

Comment: Have you considered using sqlite, though?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using an XML Database (eXist-db is opensource and worth a try). It's exactly the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DataNucleus frameowrk,it let to you use JDO for access to "database". The database can be XML archives (an others). So if you decide in any moment migrate to a RDBMS the impact will be minimun. Check the following doc:

> DataNucleus supports persisting/retrieving objects to/from XML
>   documents (using the datanucleus-xml plugin). It makes use of JAXB.

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/xml/support.html

Answer (score 0):

This should not be very difficult: if you do not have to query contents but just do id lookups, you can store XML content as BLOB (note: CLOBs are not as good, despite what many think). If so, serialize/deserialize using JAXB (byte[] from POJO, POJO from byte[]), pass that to DB using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you might want to use [xPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp) to make "queries" on your file... [syntax here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Use [DAO](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/) to easily structure your information..

but if it's a lightweight application.. why don't you use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? ... it's really easy to use and the user doesn't need any port open or something..